# ¿Diferencia de performance al consultar con SELECT DISTINCT y GROUP BY?

Tags: sql

Estoy repasando y aprendiendo SQL, hay algo que note que me parece curioso.

Supongamos que tengo una tabla llamada `productos` y uno de sus campos es `categoria`, al hacer las siguientes consultas veo que el resultado es el mismo:

```
SELECT DISTINCT categoria FROM productos;
```

y

```
SELECT categoria FROM productos GROUP BY categoria;
```

La diferencia que noto es que con `DISTINCT` me filtra los duplicados y respeta el orden en el que aparecen, mientras que con la sentencia que emplea `GROUP BY` las organiza en orden alfabetico. Basado en eso se puede decir que ¿la primera sentencia se ejecuta mas rápido?. De ser así al manejar grandes volúmenes de datos, ¿la diferencia en perfomance sería considerable?

Comment: En mi opinión la pregunta es muy general, ya que no hablas de un motor en particular, y los temas de desempeño van bastante amarrados a la estrategia seguida por el motor que utilices, sus capacidades para plantear un plan óptimo, etc. Además, mencionas que con `distinct` _filtra los duplicados_, lo que parece implicar que con group by si aparecen duplicados, lo cuál, si fuera así, sería un bug en el motor que estás utilizando.

Comment: @jachguate interesa tanto conocer de cual db se esta utilizando?, basicamente estos comandos sql a nivel funcional deberias aplicar de la misma forma, puede que cambien la performance de un motor de db a otro, pero bueno si ese es el caso creo que era la idea comentarlo.

Comment: @Leandro, vos mismo te has respondido, ya que la pregunta es sobre desempeño, y justamente el desempeño es lo que cambia entre un motor y otro, tal como dice mi primer comentario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `DISTINCT` elimina los registros duplicados, la función `GROUP BY` se implementa para agrupar registros.

La función `DISTINCT` se ejecuta de la siguiente forma:

- Copia todos `business_key` valores a una tabla temporal
- Ordena la tabla temporal
- Analiza la tabla temporal, retornando cada elemento que es diferente de la anterior

La función `GROUP BY` se ejecuta como:

- Busque en la tabla llena, almacena cada `business_key` en un `hashtable`
- Retorna las llaves del `hashtable`

El primero optimiza la memoria, en cambio el segundo optimiza la velocidad pero requiere gran cantidad de memoria dependiendo la cantidad de llaves.

Saludos.

Comment: Hay motores donde las tablas temporales o las `hashtable` no existen. La pregunta no menciona un motor en particular, y parece que estar respuesta está basada en uno

Comment: Hasta donde se, en los sistemas de bases de datos multi-nodo, los hashtable se utilizan comúnmente para distribuir filas entre los nodos

Comment: se utilizan comúnmente, puedo aceptarlo, pero ¿en todos?. Tu respuesta no hace la diferencia entre unos y otros, sino que implica que todos los motores hacen lo mismo, y no lo creo ni de lejos.

Answer (score 7):

Si bien esta claro que ambas técnicas obtienen el mismo resultado final, no todas se verían como válidas por el resultado que quieres conseguir.

Teniendo en cuenta el planteo que realizas lo correcto sería usar el `DISTINCT`, ya que este aplica sobre la row, en cambio el `GROUP BY` fue creado para trabajar con agregaciones como ser el `SUM()`, `MAX()`, `AVG()`, etc.

El tema del orden no seria problemas porque con un `ORDER BY` resolvería la diferencia.

En estos links, aunque estén en inglés, se planteó el mismo tema:

- [Is there any difference between GROUP BY and DISTINCT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164319/is-there-any-difference-between-group-by-and-distinct)
- [What is the difference between GROUP BY and DISTINCT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720105/what-is-the-difference-between-group-by-and-distinct)

Comment: Entonces, ¿cuál es la diferencia de performance? No se comprende eso en tu respuesta.

Comment: La diferencia va a depender del contexto de la prueba, si se realiza con solo un puñado de registros no hay diferencia, pero si lo haces con varios miles la cosa cambia. Tambien depende si se aplica sobre campos indexados o no (aqui lo mejor es analizar el plan de ejecucion en el Sql Server Management Studio). Mi respuesta apunta a que cada instruccion se creo con un objetivo claro, se puede clavar un clavo con una tenaza, si seguro se pueda, ahora es lo correcto, me temo que no, entonces si se busca obtener diferencias usas el DISCTINCT, ahora si buscas agrupar usas el GROUP BY.

Comment: Tu respuesta sigue sin responder la pregunta...

Answer (score 2):

`GROUP BY` se utiliza mas para operaciones del tipo: `count`, `sum`, etc.

Dependiendo de la cantidad de registros de la tabla (hablando de millones de registros), el `select` (sea con `distinct` o con `group by`) tardarán mas o menos el mismo tiempo

Si el caso es que la tabla tiene millones de registros (100, 200, 500), a veces lo mejor es extraer la data que quieres agrupar en una tabla temporal (`select ... insert`) y sobre la tabla temporal ejecutar el `distinct` o el `group by`.  El tiempo de consulta es considerablemente mucho mas rapído.

Comment: Hay motores donde las tablas temporales no existen. La pregunta no menciona un motor en particular, y parece que estar respuesta está basada en uno.

Answer (score 2):

Adicional a lo que comenta Leandro y como fiel traducción de una de las respuestas del link que él mismo adjunta, la respuesta varia entre motor pero puedes tener un alcance de estos dos motores de base de datos:

**RPTA:**

**No hay diferencia** (en SQL Server, por lo menos) Ambas consultas usan el mismo plan de ejecución.

http://sqlmag.com/database-performance-tuning/distinct-vs-group

Quizás haya una diferencia, si  hay subconsultas involucradas:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/29/sql-server-difference-between-distinct-and-group-by-distinct-vs-group-by/

**No hay diferencia** (estilo-Oracle):

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:32961403234212

- [Respuesta original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/164485/3957327)

Answer (score 0):

La primera opción, solo filtra las filas conforme las va encontrando pero tiene que recorrerlas todas para obtener el resultado. Cuando usas `group by` el resultado primario obtenido se vuelve a procesar para ordenarlo de acuerdo con el valor de la agrupación, en tu caso, por "categoría". Sin usar índices es más rápida la primera opción. Sin embargo si colocas un índice al campo "categoría" entonces la consulta con `group by` es prácticamente igual de rápida. Hay que tener en cuenta que cada alternativa se utiliza de acuerdo al resultado que necesites.

Comment: Diría que esta información puede ser cierta en algunos motores, y no cierta en otros.